# Prevent redirect to www if it is approved subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the below the redirect from http://example.com to https://www.example.com

```
 # redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # redirect http(s)://example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, it also redirects `subdomain.example.com` to `www.subdomain.example.com` - how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
# redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # redirect http(s):// example.com to https://www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   #exclude subdomain
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.example\.com$  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: works like a charm thx. any possibility to exchange `example` and `com` to dynamic?